# What happened to `vga=ask` in newer kernels?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, framebuffer

I used to activate framebuffer mode in the "older" kernels with `vga=ask`, and later setting it to a value, once I've figured out which one works best for me.

Now, this option seems to be gone, the 3.11 kernel tells me it ignores this legacy option.

What should I use instead, when activating framebuffer mode for the text mode consoles and the boot process?

Comment: ISTR some command line tool being used for this instead now...

Comment: What is your video card? From my experience, most modern cards (Intel, nVidia, ATI/AMD) automatically enter the framebuffer mode upon boot.

Comment: @Renan I have an nVidia GeForce 9600 iirc. It seems to not detect my dual monitor setup. Also, I've never got to have the framebuffer working in 1080p. Is there a way to force framebuffer mode?

Answer (score 2):

KMS-enabled kernels overrule any `vga=` setting before `init` completes, when modesetting is initiated, functionally making whether `vga=ask` works or not moot.

Instead, use `video=` with the specific mode desired on the vttys. With `video=`, you're not limited to VESA modes - any mode supported by the display can be used. It's even possible sometimes with `video=` to specify modes that a display doesn't natively support, though the result can be ugly, e.g. 2048x1024 on a 1920x1200 native display.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/modedb.txt for video= documentation.

Answer (score -3):

#### You don't need too.

Newer kernel are not using framebuffer at all, instead modesetting is now the default.

Modesetting should be able to provide you best possible resolution your monitor/vga can support.

Comment: oookay... How do I do that? A Link to a Documentation, maybe?

Comment: that's the best part, you don't need to do anything! mode setting is full automated. simply having it enabled in kernel should do the trick

Comment: Well, it doesn't do anything as of yet, and it's not switching into framebuffer mode at boot.

Comment: There are many caveats for this, such as it only works with certain video drivers (and the common proprietary nvidia drivers are not one of them), KMS must be enabled in the kernel, and some modules require it to be turned on (`i915.modeset=1` for example).

Comment: @Patrick I do use the proprietary nvidia drivers! I remember it still *kinda* working, though. Could you link something more specific, or add an answer?